# Hue integration with Amazon Athena

Tags: amazon-s3, hue, amazon-athena

My requirement:

I want user authentication(read only access) to run sql queries over amazon athena. Athena will be used to run read only queries over s3.
Hue will be used for user authentication instead of direct access to Athena.

So I think with the help of Hue, this can be achievable.
But I'm unable to find the clear way to do apache hue integration with Athena.

Answer (score 0):

Hue login has nothing to do with Athena's credential management.

1. Setup users in Athena (however you do that, I don't know. [Seems like IAM bucket policies](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/security.html))
2. Download Athena's JDBC driver.
3. Copy driver into Hue and [configure it for the JDBC notebook interface](http://gethue.com/custom-sql-query-editors/)

You will be prompted for login credentials from the JDBC connection

Comment: Thanks @cricket_007

I did following changes and it works.

1. Modification in jdbc.py
2. Integrated Hue with LDAP.

Comment: @SunLynx What modifications did you need to make? Can you make a Pull Request to Hue on Github and provide the code in an answer here?

Comment: Here is the complete jdbc.py 
[https://github.com/Lawands/hue-jdbc.py/blob/master/la]

Comment: Thanks! Would you like to make a PR? https://github.com/cloudera/hue/pulls